# Memory/motherboard testing

Tags: laptop, upgrade, memory

After replacing 1GB RAM module with 2GB one in Asus F3Sg laptop, thus taking total RAM to 4GB I started experiencing weird issues.

Applications would crash, causing numerous logical errors on HDD. (64bit Ubuntu, ext3, latest BIOS).

However, memtest86+ highlights no issues and as soon as I revert back to 3GB of RAM issues disappear. Both 2GB modules (PC2-5300) seem to be healthy and work perfectly when paired with 1GB module, but cause aforementioned issues when used together.

So question is - is there more comprehensive set of tests than memtest86, possibly allowing me to reveal the underlying issue (motherboard? RAM? HDD?)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not to presume it is a hardware issue. It might very well be, but I would keep my eyes open for software incompatibilities as well. The fact that you are booting to 64 bit kernel could be a potential cause of the kind of errors you are seeing.

If you are using grub, you might want to have a look at the 'mem=' option available.

All that said, it could be a hardware error as well. You could check if Asus offers any built in diagnostic tests.

Comment: Moving to newer version of Kernel fixed the issue.

Comment: Good to know that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would presume [failing capacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague#Symptoms) which might cause memory errors, especially if they buffer the power line to the RAMs. If you put more modules into the board a failure is more likely. Solution: either identify and replace the capacitors which may be possible in some cases. Perhaps you can try a 4 GB module instead of two 2 GB or life with 3 GB. I have an older Dell notebook here in our office with exactly the same problem.

Comment: I am not adding new modules per se, I am just replacing 1GB one with 2 GB. However, it still migth be the case that it drain more power, I suppose. MB would only take max of 4GB total (2GB for each slot), unfortunately. Asus does not provide any support for non-Vista 32 bit OS for this laptop. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Ultra-X](http://www.uxd.com/) makes the best memory testing tool, RST. There is a [USB version](http://www.rst.com/rst-usb.shtml) for laptops, but it isn't free.